# How to use Ruby on Rails functions within plain (non ROR) Ruby file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ruby on Rails contains some very useful functions like `blank?` and date time functions that are not present in vanilla ruby.

What is the gem to enables these and how do I use it?

Answer (score 8):

The gem you are referring to is [`ActiveSupport`](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activesupport) and the features can be loaded all at once from 
[`core_ext.rb`](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext) (which loads each file in the [core_ext Directory](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext)) e.g.

```
require 'active_support/core_ext'
```

or loaded individually based the features and classes you are interested in
e.g.

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/object/blank'
```